# Historical definition of a group

Tags: group-theory, math-history

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_group_theory) states that van Dyck (1882) was the first to give the definition of a group in the modern way.  Before this, what were some of the original axioms or conditions for groups?  I mean, how were groups originally defined/restricted?  I understand groups were originally studied as groups of permutations, but that is all I know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia page looks pretty complete to me.

Like all other main concepts in mathematics, it took time for a precise definition of a group to arise; it was never axiomatized from the start.

See also the book [A History of Abstract Algebra](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/historyofscience/book/978-0-8176-4684-4) and the articles 
[The Foundation Period in the History of Group Theory](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2972411) and [The Evolution of Group Theory: A Brief Survey](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=1399).

Comment: Thanks for the extra links.  That last article is a great, relaxing read and answers my question to a tee.