# structure-preserving: a history?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, math-history

I am familiar with the occurrence of structure-preserving morphisms in Category Theory, but I would love to know more about the history of the concept, where it started and so on? I suspect it might be due to Noether or people form those days, but I am not sure and would welcome any specific reference from your side

Best regards and thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sure it started before Noether, starting with the concept of homomorphisms https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2750817 or even Euclidean geometry's similarity/congruence

Comment: well. I do not mean homomorphism, but the concept and expresson  structure-preserving...that is what I am interested in :)

Comment: Probably a good starting point is Felix Klein's *Erlangen program*.  You see some parts of the general idea, but that could be Whig history (with Eilenberg and MacLane's seminal paper *General Theory of Natural Equivalence* claiming category theory as a continuation of the Erlangen program).  Pre-Bourbaki, it would seem that each was dealing with a specific structure (groups, rings, topology, etc.) although there are many who believed that some unifying mathematical ideas exist (especially since before 1910s mathematics is small enough for one person to know it all, e.g. Hilbert or Poincare).